# PHP script stops execution after some time on iis 8

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I am running a PHP script on iis 8. I've set max_execution_time to 0 using `ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);` set `memory_limit` to '-1' using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and 15 minute limit for FastCGI. At above 1 minutes that would be returning 500 Internal server error.

This is on a windows 2012 R2 server using PHP Version 5.6.

Anyone have any ideas why this keeps ending after 1 minutes even when I specifically set it for a longer period?

Comment: Can you add details as to what you're running and why you think that execution time has anything to do with it. A 500 error can have a wide range of errors.

Comment: @Peter4499 I am using a for loop in PHP script that take a long time so need to set max_execution_time.

Comment: how and where are you setting limits for fastcgi? on unix/apache I would set  fcgididletimeout (https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#). on windows I am guessing idleTimeout (https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi?showTreeNavigation=true)